# As each of them touches down... is it touch or touches?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Context: Paratroopers are landing.

My brain says it should be: "As each of them touch down,..."

but then again, it could be

"As each of them touches down,..."

You could argue that plural noun/pronoun goes with plural verb but "they" is a plural pronoun and would go with "touch" not touches, and "each" could go with "touch" if "each touch" did something.

Answer (score 4):

> As each of them touches down ...

(singular subject)

or

> As they touch down ...

(plural subject)

Answer (score 2):

**Each of/each one of/every one of** are followed by plural noun of pronoun but the verb is usually singular. When we use each we talk about every individual.

Answer (score 0):

*As **each** of them touches*

Each describes individuals.

Comment: This is correct, but awfully sparse.

Answer (score -3):

Definitely, the verb should be singular.  Look up in the section of "subject-verb agreement" of any grammar book, plz.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation. The question is not about agreement, but about which are the words to consider in the agreement.

Comment: IN the context where paratroopers are talked about, you may just say " as they touch down..." I can't understand why each should be used in this context. Yey, when each is the subject, the verb has to be "touches."

Comment: 1. The additional explanation must be in the answer, not in the comment. 2. If you do not understand something, you should not provide answers - you are always welcome to post your own questions. 3. The additional explanation is not any more clear than the original answer.